# How to make some character "unreadable" as text in the pdf output but still visible?

Tags: spacing, pdf, transparency, phantom

This question might be seen is a follow up/complement [to this question and answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/370055/50886). I'm actually taking the example from there:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{transparent}
\begin{document}
horse

ho\phantom{r}se

ho\textcolor{white}{r}se

ho\makebox[0pt]{{\transparent{0}r}}se
\end{document}
```

Four times the word **horse**. The first one is the regular word. The 2nd appears as **ho se**, because the **r** is invisible. The third also appears as **ho se**, but in contrast with the previous case, the word "horse" is contained in the document (appears as a search result, the copy/paste of the text, and the output of `pdftotext`). The last example appears as **hose** visually, but the text "horse" is contained in the pdf.

I need a the opposite case: I want the **r** to be visible but not contained in the text of the pdf. In other words, I want to be able to see the word **horse** on the pdf, but when searching the document (or mouse select + copy/paste, or `pdftotext` output), only the word "hose" appears.

Is this possible?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58851/87678

Comment: From my brief looking around, if you want to do this just for some words, the only option seems to be the `pst-text` package, which means you are stuck with `latex→dvips→ps2pdf`. If you want to do it for the whole document, you can use `ghostscript` to outline all fonts.

Comment: Or if you *only* need the word horse, you could make the letter in `inkscape` and include it as a `tikz` picture.

Comment: I don't know why, with MikTeX your example doesn't compile and says `! Undefined control sequence <argument> {\transparent{0}r}`

Comment: Are you using `pdflatex` @AndréC? `\transparent` only works in PDF mode, not dvi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the `accsupp` (Accessibility Support) package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\begin{document}
\BeginAccSupp{ActualText=hose}%
horse%
\EndAccSupp{}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
$ pdftotext test.pdf -
hose

1
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Henri-Menke. Quite a hack for the PDF. Never even crossed my mind searching for accessibility options, but it makes sense. Thanks again

Comment: If you use another ripper (`pdf2txt.py test.pdf`) you can see the horse is still in your PDF.

Comment: @abukaj If you want to really obfuscate the PDF, so that no text can be recovered without OCR, you have to take further steps, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11307/is-it-possible-to-produce-a-pdf-with-un-copyable-text

Comment: @HenriMenke I want the exact opposite (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/680303/how-to-convert-a-dash-to-a-minus-for-ats-only) - right now some characters in the PDF (`--`) are read by the reaper and misinterpreted.  I want to force the reaper to see `-` where `--` is displayed.  But the link you provided may help, thanks!